# SQL Server 2008 R2 Maintenance Plan Logging

Tags: sql-server-2008, maintenance-plan

Does anyone know what table contains information that stores the folder that Maintenance Plan Reporting and Logging uses? I've searched every table in the MSDB that is named even remotely like it might contain it and so far I've come up empty.  There are plenty of examples on the web related to viewing the maintenance plan information but none mention this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this. Unfortunately, it is not stored in the MSDB but is stored in the SSIS package itself as part of the XML.